# Report coefficients and exponentiated coefficients side by side with stargazer

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

How does one add a column to the model output that includes say the exponentiated values of the coefficients next to the unexponentiated values of the coefficients? Is this what the add.lines option is for? Thanks for any help.

```
#load library
library(stargazer)
#sample data
var1<-sample(c('men', 'women'), replace=TRUE, 100, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))
var2<-sample(c('left', 'right'), replace=TRUE, 100, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
df<-data.frame(gender=var1, vote=var2)
#binomial logistic regression
model1<-glm(vote~gender, data=df, family='binomial')
#report model without
stargazer(model1)
#report model with exponentiated coefficients
stargazer(model1, apply.coef=exp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way, but what about a quick hack like this:

```
model1Exp = model1 
model1Exp$coefficients = exp(model1Exp$coefficients)

stargazer(model1, model1Exp)
```

You'll need to adjust the default labels to mark the fact that the second model is the same as the first, but with exponentiated coefficients.

Comment: I can dig it.  I'll hold off on accepting it as an answer to give someone a chance to show a way to do it within stargazer. Pretty clever tho.

Comment: So, this worked.  However, one hitch was that in the second model, it uses p-values of the first model (i.e. the ratio of the unexponentiated coefficients to the standard error) to decide whether to print significance stars in the second model (where the coefficients have been exponentiated). This leads to discrepancies.  I fixed this by adding the argument to the stargazer command.  `code` p=list(coef(summary(model1))[,5], coef(summary(model1))[,5] `code`

Comment: Now, the only thing is, I'd like to actually figure out how to suppress the standard errors of the second model, but report them for the first model.  Is that possible?